# Is is possible to hide GiftAid details if someone selects 'no'?

Tags: custom-fields, gift-aid-extension

We're using the GiftAid plugin which is great.

However, if someone declines to use GiftAid the fields are still present and compulsory to fill in.

Is there any way to make them conditional on selecting Yes, or Yes in the past 4 years?

I appreciate they will still need to give the billing details on the card payment, but it's a little confusing to have to fill in data when you've deselected an option.

Thanks in advance,
John

Wordpress 5.5.1 / CiviCRM 5.30.0 / PHP version 7.3.23 / UK Gift Aid (uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid) version 3.4.5